# How to delete dynamically created table rows without refreshing (preferentially with the standard swipe-to-left-animation)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry, but I have to ask one more question. Google couldn´t help me :(
I try to create a user control management in a CMS. 
The problem is that I am completely knew to javascript and jQuery and I have to delete a table row on button click without refreshing the page. The idea is to set the row display:hidden, but I don´t know how to get the id of a row.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    $abfrage= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id asc");
    //$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage) or die( mysql_error() ); 
    echo "<table>";
    echo"<caption>Mitglieder<br></caption>";
    echo"<table border=\"1\" style=\"width:300px\">";
     echo "<th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Vorname</th>
        <th>Rolle</th>
        <th>Funktionen</th>";
    //loop, um alle Nutzer zu identifizieren    
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($abfrage))
{

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td align=center id =",$row->id,">",$row->id,"</td>";
  echo "<td align=center>" ,$row->Name,"</td>";
  echo "<td align=center>",$row->Vorname,"</td>";
  //Vorbelegung
  echo "<td align=center><select><option selected = \"selected\">",$row->Rolle,"</option>";
  //loop, um alle Rollen zu identifizieren. AKTUELL: doppelte Rollen werden noch doppelt angezeigt. Eventuell Rollen auslaagern
  $file = mysql_query("SELECT Rolle FROM user WHERE 1");
    while ($role = mysql_fetch_row($file)) 
    {
        if ($role[0]!= $row->Rolle) {
              echo "<option value=".$role[0].">",$role[0],"</option>";
        } 



    }

  echo "</select></td>";
  echo  "<td align=center><button type = \"button\" onCLick = \"deleteUser()\">Löschen</button></td>";


}
echo "</table>";
?>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteUser() {
    alert("And it works");
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none'


}
</script>
</html>
```

The problem is here:

```
echo "<td align=center id =",$row->id,">",$row->id,"</td>";
```

Is this the right way to create an id to every row?

And if somebody knows how to realize it, I want to have an "deleting" (Deleting is obviously the wrong word because it is only hidden) animation.

Thank you in advance!

Ps: I know, that I have to change mysl to SQLi :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really a FAN of JQuery because makes you forgeth the very basics of Javascript! it really simplyfies some things but... hmm dunno!

maybe this "function" could help you:

```
function dropRow(rowId) {
    try {
        var tblResponse= document.getElementById('tblResponse');    
        var rowCount = tblResponse.rows.length;

        for(ix=0; ix < rowCount;ix++) {
            var row = tblResponse.rows[ix];
            var id = row.cells[0].childNodes[0].id; //The ID of something what identifies the Row
            if(id == 'dropRow'+rowId) {
                tblResponse.deleteRow(ix);
                rowCount--;
                ix--;
            }
        }
    }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `remove` function within jQuery.

You will want to give the ID to the `<tr>` and not a `<td>` within the row, next your `deleteUser` function should take the "id" as an argument, and finally you should delete the row from within the `deleteUser` function. But you will need a way to inform your database that the user has been deleted, perhaps ajax to an API might work but I don't know how you have your system set up.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function deleteUser(id){
      $(id).remove();
      // Do something to let the server know the user was deleted
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
    $abfrage= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id asc");
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<caption>Mitglieder<br></caption>";
    echo "<table border=\"1\" style=\"width:300px\">";
    echo "<thead><tr><td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Vorname</td><td>Rolle</td><td>Funktionen</td></td><thead>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($abfrage)){
      echo "<tr id='".$row->id."'>";
        echo "<td align='center'>".$row->id."</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>".$row->Name."</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>".$row->Vorname."</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'><select><option selected=\"selected\">".$row->Rolle."</option>";
        $file = mysql_query("SELECT Rolle FROM user WHERE 1");
        while ($role = mysql_fetch_row($file)){
          if ($role[0]!= $row->Rolle)
            echo "<option value=".$role[0].">".$role[0]."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select></td>";
        echo "<td align='center'><button type = \"button\" onclick = \"deleteUser(".$row->id.")\">Löschen</button></td>";
      echo "</tr>"
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```